# MVC dropDown Filter doesn't postback the selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating my first sample MVC based sample app.

I have a model:-

```
 public class SampleClass
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Range(1,100)]
        public int Age { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Created On")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }

        public string itemGenre { get; set; }

    }
```

An Index.cshtml page that shows:-

```
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Sample", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <p style="margin-bottom:30px;">

            <div style="display:inline-block; float:left; border:1px dotted black; padding:20px;">
                Created Date: @Html.TextBox("fromDate")
                <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
            </div>

            <div style="display: inline-block; border: 1px dotted black; padding: 20px; margin-left:170px;">
                Genre: @Html.DropDownList("itemGenre", "All")
            </div>

            <div style="display: inline-block; float: right; border: 1px dotted black; padding: 20px;">
                Search: @Html.TextBox("searchString")
                <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
            </div>
        </p>
    }

</p>
```

I have got my filter methods for CreatedDate and SearchString to work correctly. But I cannot seem to get my DropDown menu filter "itemGenre" to work properly. Although my dropdown menu populates with the correct values/strings stored in my database, every time I do a postback, the itemGenre is retrieved as a null value in my controller class:-

```
        public ActionResult Index(DateTime? fromDate, string itemGenere, string searchString)
        {

            var GenreList = new List<string>();
            var GenreQuery = from d in db.Sample
                             orderby d.itemGenre
                             select d.itemGenre;
            GenreList.AddRange(GenreQuery.Distinct());
            ViewBag.itemGenre = new SelectList(GenreList);

            var items = from i in db.Sample
                        select i;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                items = items.Where(o => o.Description.Contains(searchString));
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(fromDate)))
            {
                items = items.Where(p => p.CreatedDate >= fromDate);
            }

            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(itemGenere))
            {
                items = items.Where(q => q.itemGenre == itemGenere);
            }

            return View(items);

        }
```

I would like to know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Because `itemGenre` (dropdownlist name) is not `itemGenere` (method parameter). Use view models and the strongly types html helpers

Comment: wow. Spelling error.....thank you Stephen.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Is there a way to make the dropdown menu filter dynamic, as soon as there is a selection, the search in the controller is initiated, rather than having to do a manual filter postback?

Comment: You would need javascript/jquery to handle the `.change()` event of the dropdownlist and submit the form (but that's not the normal expected behavior so I would not recommend it). And you would get better performance if you use ajax to post the values and update the DOM without a full page refresh